# Will the KVM enabled kernel work with LUKS whole disk encryption on 18.04?

Tags: boot, kernel, encryption, kvm-virtualization, luks

I have got a fresh installation of 18.04 with the whole disk encryption (LUKS) enabled.

This works fine, but when I try to install a KVM enabled kernel (package linux-kvm), then I am unable to boot with that image, as if the intallation process didn't take into account the disk encryption. The boot freezes on "Loading the initial ramdisk".

I wonder is this a bug in the installation scripts and is there a workaround that I could use to mek it boot correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux-kvm package provides a kernel to run inside KVM virtual machines. It is not intended to run on the VM host; use the regular Ubuntu Linux image for the host.